# Display javascript alert with Internet Explorer conditional comment

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, alert

The design of my website is pretty ugly with versions of Internet Explorer smaller than 7.
I'd like to display a javascript alert for the users whose browser is concerned.

Something like : "The design of the website is not optimized for your browser. Please upgrade ... "

The thing is that javascript code inside conditional comments doesn't work so how can I do this ?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.browserupgrade.info/tools/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script>alert("IE 6");</script>
<![endif]-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W9gPQ/1/

I wouldn't do this if I were you, though. An `alert()` is terribly obtrusive. Why not just show a `div`.

Comment: Whether or not it works in IE 8 is kind of irrelevant, given it's intended for versions lower than 7. I'll agree that an alert is an awful way of doing it, though.

Comment: @Anthony I'm fairly sure the way conditional comments are parsed is identical in all versions. But you have a point. I'll fire up a VM with IE6 to make sure

Answer (score 0):

The alert will work fine, in the sites where javascriptting is allowed. The following code part will be used to show an alert

```
<script>
alert("Your Message");
</script>
```

Refer to [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Getting_Started) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s some great info about Conditional comments; http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

...and perhaps this IE 6 block script can inspire you; http://css-tricks.com/955-ie-6-blocker-script/

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just made a jQuery plugin to solve these kind of problems. Check it out on: http://nmsdvid.com/iealert/